# Compare Data between 2 DW Tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, compare, data-warehouse

I'm a little confused here. I'm testing some data quality issues in a DW, I need to know if the LOAN_SID in one table matches the other table. I was using this query but I'm not sure if I'm correct, if it matches there is an issue if it doesn't everything is good.

So here is the query:

```
(select count(LOAN_SID)  from DW_DW.AGG_LOAN_SS_MONTHLY
 minus
 select LOAN_SID from DW_DW.F_LOAN_UNWOUND_TRAN_DAILY) 
union all
( 
 select LOAN_SID  from DW_DW.F_LOAN_UNWOUND_TRAN_DAILY
 minus
 select LOAN_SID from DW_DW.AGG_LOAN_SS_MONTHLY
)
```

Here is the other:

```
SELECT  LOAN_SID
FROM DW_DW.AGG_LOAN_SS_MONTHLY A  
WHERE not EXISTS (SELECT LOAN_SID 
                  FROM DW_DW.F_LOAN_UNWOUND_TRAN_DAILY B
                  WHERE A.LOAN_SID = B.LOAN_SID);
```

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this gives all the sid that are unique in both tables. It is not a terribly efficient query and should not be run on large tables without some testing.

```
 select * from
( (select LOAN_SID, 'F_LOAN_UNWOUND_TRAN_DAILY' AS SOURCE  
 from DW_DW.F_LOAN_UNWOUND_TRAN_DAILY
 minus
 select LOAN_SID, 'AGG_LOAN_SS_MONTHLY'
 from DW_DW.AGG_LOAN_SS_MONTHLY)
UNION ALL
 ( select LOAN_SID, 'AGG_LOAN_SS_MONTHLY' AS SOURCE  
 from DW_DW.AGG_LOAN_SS_MONTHLY)
 minus
select LOAN_SID, 'F_LOAN_UNWOUND_TRAN_DAILY' 
 from DW_DW.F_LOAN_UNWOUND_TRAN_DAILY))
```

To get the SIDS that are in both tables

```
select a.LOAD_SID
from DW_DW.AGG_LOAN_SS_MONTHLY a, DW_DW.F_LOAN_UNWOUND_TRAN_DAILY b
where a.LOAN_SID = b.LOAN_SID;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, How can I get the ones that are the same in both tables?